# Geirim and accepting Mitzvos

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, maseches-shabbos

The Gemara in Shabbos says that a Geir Shenisgayer Bein Hagoyim is considered Jewish and has to bring a Chatas for his chillul Shabbos.

If he grew up among goyim, how can he actually accept the mitzvos? He is completely ignorant of the halachos, how can he fully accept mitzvos? Is this a proof that a ger doesn't need kabalas hamitzvos?

Comment: One can accept the mitzvos without knowing what they are. It is a foolish, but halachically significant act.

Comment: I assume your question is on the _g'mara_ rather than a practical one, right? Because, I mean, nowadays it's easy for people _ben hagoyim_ to read all about _mitzvos_.

Comment: @msh210, yes; but for instance, Rabbi Rakeffet suggests that if someone converts Orthodox and belongs to an Orthodox synagogue where all the people there affiliate Orthodox, never drive on shabbos, but eat salmon at non-kosher-certified restaurants, then if that convert does it too, it's no challenge to the sincerity of the conversion -- s/he is looking around at the common practice, figuring that's fully keeping the mitzvos, and following it.

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein uses this as proof that if a person sincerely accepted all the mitzvos to the best of their understanding, but that understanding was incomplete, that the conversion is valid. Still requires a commitment, though.

Comment: Could you please source your answer